# Google Maps openNowStatus always return unknown (status 2)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places

I'm developing an app in iOS, and when I'm using the Google Maps API, I've a problem with `openNowStatus`. It always return an error: **2 (Unknown)**.

Any suggestion?

Thanks an advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [forum](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9190&q=type%3DDefect%20apitype%3DPlacesAPI%20apitype%3APlacesAPI&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal), the parameter should be `opennow` and not `openNow` parameter. Be mindful that parameters are case sensitive. Check if it works. This might be also a bug based from this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8160&q=type%3DDefect%20apitype%3DPlacesAPI%20apitype%3APlacesAPI&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal).

Comment: Actually, i'm calling lookUpPlaceId and return correct information, except openNowStatus, that seems a bug such as it's described in your second link (is exactly the same problem). Thanks!